# Unable to create xDB contact on CM server

Tags: xdb, xconnect

I am unable to create a contact in xDB in a scaled CM server with the below code, whereas the same code is working on the dev Server.

I believe `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Session.IdentifyAs` is not creating the contact and I am getting `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error while setting the Personal Facet (because currentContact is null).

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();

Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Session.IdentifyAs(contactus.telephone, contactus.email);
var currentContact = client.Get<Contact>(new IdentifiedContactReference(contactus.telephone, contactus.email), new Sitecore.XConnect.ContactExpandOptions());

if(currentContact ==null)
{
    new Logger().Info("CreateContact : session  contact is null");
}
```

Getting  Log entry "CreateContact : session  contact is null" always in staged CM but not on dev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check  what role is configured on **web.config Stage CM** server  ? 
I am refering to this setting:

```
 <!-- SUPPORTED SERVER ROLES
         Specify the roles that you want this server to perform. A server can perform one or more roles. Enter the roles in a comma separated list. The supported roles are:

         ContentDelivery
         ContentManagement
         Processing
         Reporting
         Standalone

    Default value: Standalone
    -->
    <add key="role:define" value="Standalone,Local" />
```

If is **"ContentManagement"** server is a normal behavior because Tracking is not working on CM server.

Can you check on **Dev** environment if you have Standalone role configured.

Comment: this is a normal behaviour. If you changed on Stage to Standalone will not crash. I suggest you to test analytics on CD servers not on CM.

Comment: Yes , It works . Marked your  Answer as accepted